# What book has space arks crewed by slaves leaving earth?

Tags: story-identification, religion, hard-sci-fi

I will give as much detail as I can remember. I first read the book in 1980.
I have searched sci-fi books back to the 1940's and still can't find this book. I believe it may either be a really old book, one that was renamed, or something that was dismissed as pulp sci-fi. The writing and story were pretty good, so I'm surprised I can't find it.

The book starts on Earth with a powerful ruling class that forms their own religion. 
The first high priest starts a dynasty and all subsequent rulers use his name followed by a roman numeral (like Egyptian Pharaohs or Popes). Before the end of his life, the first high priest has himself frozen so that he can be resurrected to a time when science can make him immortal. Subsequent rulers do the same, but the first high priest has deemed that their cryo units will kill them before they awake. There can be only one master.

This next part I may have confused with another book - All goes well until they discover that the Sun is going to expand and swallow the Earth. Maybe they just leave Earth for another reason, but they do leave in mass.

This part I do remember -They send out interplanetary probes and design spaceships. They finally find suitable planets and create several "Arks" (I think there were multiple, can't be sure). They put all the ruling class into cryo sleep, and crew the ships with "slaves" who are trained to maintain the equipment.

Aboard the ships, the crews live in a caste system where duties are passed down from father to son. It will take many generations before they arrive at the host planet, and the last generation will again be slaves of the sleeping masters. Something goes wrong and the ship's food system is destroyed. One of the slave mechanics investigates and finds the sleeping masters. He find ancient records and discovers the fate in store for them. The crew decides they will not be slaves again, and will save themselves by eating the frozen masters until they arrive at the planet.

The ship lands on the planet and they crew prepare a final ship's meal. The last cryo-chamber to be opened is very ornate and old. It is actually the first high priest froze many years ago. He is accidentally awakened because his cryo-chamber is automatically activated when opened. He expects that he will be worshiped and soon will watch "hot knives plunged into quivering pink flesh". He sees the common young girl who has opened his cryo-chamber and begins to shout orders at her. Before he can say anything, she cuts his throat and he is prepared for the first feast on the new planet.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You really are a guardian-editor. May the badges be with you!

Comment: @Einer: [read ’em and weep (at how I spend my life)](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/copy-editor)

Comment: Elements of this sound suspiciously like Mayflower II (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resplendent)

Comment: I believe Mayflower II was published in 2004, which was 14 years after I read this book. It does sound very similar in many respects.

Comment: @user26266 - I was getting a lovely long answer ready, to explain how you were wrong about the date and clearly meant 2000, not 1980.

Comment: Reading it, I think you might actually be mixing these two stories up. Mayflower has the cannibalism aspect whereas Songs of Distant Earth has the earthbound bit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure about the date. It was during high school for me (1980-1983) and I had also purchased Billy Joel's 52nd Street album (1978) with the book. The two are forever linked in my brain. If I can find the name of the book, I will play the album and read as I did so many years ago. I am a big Clarke fan and have read Songs a few times. I wish it was the same book, but it isn't. I read the synopsis of Mayflower, but it doesn't match.

Comment: @user26266 - How large was the book? What did the cover look like? Was it part of an anthology, or its own story? How high did the roman numeral get in the story? When you say you might have confused the next part with another book, do you mean the reason for leaving the earth? Or everything that follows that sentence?

Comment: The book was a large novel, several hours of reading. The cover image had a lot of yellow (or gold-ish yellow) on the cover and  featured a large starship. That's what drew me to the book. I thought the word "Ark" was in the title, but subsequent title searches have proven me wrong.  I can't remember the actual Roman numeral of the last ruling priest. The confusion comes from why they left earth in the first place. I can't remember if there was a rebellion against the priests or if the Earth was falling apart. I do know the ruling class made a ship (possibly multiple) and left the planet.

Comment: As for an anthology, I don't think so. The story started and ended fully. If there was an anthology, I would love to read the other books.

Comment: Was there a main character? If so who? Which class was he/she in? If not, what was the POV of the story?

Comment: Do you remember any of the tenets of the religion? Was it a theocracy? Or more like a god-emperor type deal?

Comment: I believe the story was written in 3rd person, so the focus would shift. The first part was mainly told through the eyes of the priests. The second focused mainly on the slave tech in the Ark who found the sleeping "masters". I can't remember any character names unfortunately.

Comment: The religion was primarily a god-emperor sort of affair. very vicious and cruel as I remember. The high priest ruled with absolute power over life and death. As it developed, it became less religion and more  fascist. The priests used torture quite frequently and kept slaves to serve them.

Comment: @user26266 Does the title *Noah II* ring any bells? I can't find a plot for it, but it seems to fit *some* of the description you gave.

Comment: @amflare I was able to find some info on Roger Dixon's Noah II, and it's not the right book. You are right, it does have some similarities, but no evil cult religion. I'm starting to believe the book I want was pulp fiction and it disappeared soon after printing. I wonder if there are some sites dedicated to junk sci fi?

Answer (score 1):

[Star Gate](http://andre-norton-books.com/index.php/worlds-of-andre/novels-by-andre/267-star-gate) (novel), a 1958 novel by Andre Norton.

Not to be confused with the TV series of the same name :-)

> When Kincar s’Rud, of mixed Gorthian and Star Lord Blood, followed the
>   Star Lords through the shimmering gate that led to alternate
>   universes, he found himself on a Gorth entirely different from the
>   world he has known. At first the Gorthians appeared to be the same,
>   but his former friends, turned out to be his enemies. For they were
>   the people his friends might have been, had they made different
>   choices at crucial moments in their lives.  And soon Kincar and his
>   real allies would have to confront their own evil,
>   might-have-been-selves….

Comment: Could you expand your answer? Generally, a link to any Wiki is not a good answer, as the content of the page may change.

Comment: Honestly, the synopsis quoted in this answer doesn't sound *at all* like what the OP describes. (Well, there are evil overlords in both, but that's it.) Could this answer have been meant for some other question, and accidentally posted here?

Comment: sorry, but no. Not even close.